# How to render a structured mesh in Octave

Tags: matlab, 3d, octave

I would like to recreate this sort of "cubic" surface rendering in GNU Octave:

[image]

[From [AEG Mesher](https://github.com/flintoftid/aegmesher/) documentation]

How can I achieve this, given a list of coordinates which represent a surface or volume in a structured grid?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking for a generic tutorial on how to use this library?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou No I would like to generate a 3D plot with cubic interpolation, like rendering a line as stairs() but in 3D

Comment: Rendering a surface with surf() by default uses an unstructured mesh, triangles, but I want to render a surface by steps, cubes. The aeg mesher is just an example.

Comment: Hi Sam, got  it. Surf relies on the 'patch' command as the basic building block. The 'patch' command takes vertices and can construct patch objects, which do not have to be triangles. You can easily construct cube 'pixels'. I don't have time to write an example now, but in principle it shouldn't be too hard to create a function that creates such a patch 'pixel' at a desired location.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously there's probably much more elaborate frameworks out there, but just to demonstrate the concept: the idea that you can only work with triangular patches is incorrect. You can specify your own patches as elaborately as you want.

In the following example, I create a simple function which draws a 3D cube 'patch', to be treated as a 'pixel' element in a structured 'mesh'.

```
function drawpatchpixel( x, y, z, c )

    Vertices = [ 0, 0, 0
                 0, 1, 0
                 1, 1, 0
                 1, 0, 0
                 0, 0, 1
                 0, 1, 1
                 1, 1, 1
                 1, 0, 1 ];

    Faces = [ 1, 2, 3, 4     # front
              2, 6, 7, 3     # top
              5, 6, 7, 8     # back
              1, 5, 8, 4     # bottom
              1, 2, 6, 5     # left
              4, 3, 7, 8 ];  # right
              
    patch( 'Faces', Faces, 'Vertices', Vertices + [x, y, z], 'facecolor', c )

endfunction
```

Then I simply draw the pixels in the preferred colour:

```
Pixels = { 0, 0, 0, 'r';   # base
           1, 0, 0, 'r';
           2, 0, 0, 'r';
           3, 0, 0, 'r';
           4, 0, 0, 'r';
           4, 1, 0, 'r';
           4, 2, 0, 'r';
           4, 3, 0, 'r';
           4, 4, 0, 'r';
           3, 4, 0, 'r';
           2, 4, 0, 'r';
           1, 4, 0, 'r';
           0, 4, 0, 'r';
           0, 3, 0, 'r';
           0, 2, 0, 'r';
           0, 1, 0, 'r';

           0, 0, 1, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5];   # pillars
           0, 0, 2, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5];
           0, 0, 3, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5];
           0, 0, 4, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]; 
           4, 0, 1, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5];
           4, 0, 2, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5];
           4, 0, 3, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5];
           4, 0, 4, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]; 
           4, 4, 1, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5];
           4, 4, 2, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5];
           4, 4, 3, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5];
           4, 4, 4, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]; 
           0, 4, 1, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5];
           0, 4, 2, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5];
           0, 4, 3, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5];
           0, 4, 4, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]; 

           0, 1, 4, 'g';   # roof
           0, 2, 4, 'g';
           0, 3, 4, 'g';
           4, 1, 4, 'g';
           4, 2, 4, 'g';
           4, 3, 4, 'g';
           1, 0, 4, 'g';
           2, 0, 4, 'g';
           3, 0, 4, 'g';
           1, 4, 4, 'g';
           2, 4, 4, 'g';
           3, 4, 4, 'g';
         };

NPixels = size( Pixels, 1 );

for i = 1 : NPixels
  drawpatchpixel( Pixels{i, :} )
endfor

axis equal
view( 30, 30 )
xlabel( 'x'); ylabel('y'), zlabel('z');
camlight
```

Result:

[image]